# Money calculation javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm trying to calculate a float value in JS
I've my subtotal and I want to apply a discount in that value

I did this:

```
  $("#desconto").focusout(function(){
    var subtotal = $('#subtotal').val();
    var desconto = $('#desconto').val();

      if(desconto > 0)
        total = ((subtotal) - (desconto));
      else
        total = subtotal;

    $('#total').val(total);
    $('#totaldisabled').val(total);  
  });
```

but my results are only negative numbers, and I dont know how to fix that, I tried that too

```
parseFloat(desconto.replace(/[^\d\.]/, '')
```

but not works, can someone help me!?
thanks!

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: you indeed need to parse at some point to float cause else your values will be strings and you can't perform mathematical operations on strings. So better try to parse it as soon as you get the value (the 2 first lines in your function), and don't perform any replacement...

Comment: We need to see the markup and know the values in order to help.

Comment: For `'3.2' - '1.2'` you should get two. btw why are you trying to remove `\d\.` from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
var subtotal = $('#subtotal').val();
var desconto = $('#desconto').val();`
```

Try using:

```
var subtotal = parseFloat($('#subtotal').val());
var desconto = parseFloat($('#desconto').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#desconto").focusout(function(){
    var subtotal = $('#subtotal').val();
    var desconto = $('#desconto').val();

    subtotal = subtotal.replace('.' , '');
    subtotal = parseFloat(subtotal.replace(',' , '.'));

    desconto = desconto.replace('.' , '');
    desconto = parseFloat(desconto.replace(',' , '.'));

      if(desconto > 0)
        total = (subtotal - desconto).toFixed(2);
      else
        total = subtotal.toFixed(2);

    $('#total').val(total);
    $('#totaldisabled').val(total); 

  });//end main
```

worked! thnks everyone